# snowflake XML Parsing returns NULL - SPACE in field name?

Tags: xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get the ap id value in below xml but getting NULL back. Please help. If possible please send me a flatten query to flatten the below xml file in snowflake. I am very new to snowflake and any of your help will be much appreciated. Is this because of the space in the field name "ap id"? I doubt that. How to process the field names with space in snowflake for XML files?

select GET(lvl,'@ap id')::integer as "ap id" from
(SELECT src:"$" as lvl FROM XMLDATA);

SELECT XMLGET(SRC, 'ap id' ):"@" as "ap id"
FROM XMLDATA;

SELECT
     GET(src, '@ap id')::integer as ap_id
FROM XMLDATA;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
select src:"$"."@id" as app_id
from xmldata;
```

Here's a way to find a path by flattening and searching for a known value:

```
with xmldata as (
    select parse_xml('<amp_ap_detail><ap id="1610">asdf</ap></amp_ap_detail>') src
)
select path, value 
from xmldata, lateral flatten(input=>xmldata.src, recursive=>true) f
where value = 1610;
```

Which in this case yields:

```
PATH            VALUE
['$']['@id']    1610
```

Mapping PATH into Snowflake's field identifier notation...

```
with xmldata as(
    select parse_xml('<amp_ap_detail><ap id="1610">asdf</ap></amp_ap_detail>') src
)
select src:"$"."@id" as app_id
from xmldata;
```

Hope that's helpful.